# case tag in Universal dependencies

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am new to NLP.
While studying Universal dependency output of Stanford parser, see case tag.
Unable to find reference to this in the manual

```
root(ROOT-0, transfer-1)
dep(100-3, $-2)
dobj(transfer-1, 100-3)
case(John-5, to-4)
nmod(100-3, John-5)
case(account-8, from-6)
nmod:poss(account-8, my-7)
nmod(transfer-1, account-8)
acl(account-8, ending-9)
case(1234-11, with-10)
nmod(ending-9, 1234-11)
```

Can someone point me to update manual reference or explain significance of case tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are documented in the [Universal Dependencies manual](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/u/dep/index.html). The `case` edge is [documented here](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/u/dep/case.html). For English, this is almost always the preposition type of the incoming preposition arc. So, "*in Canada*" would have an incoming edge `nmod:in` to *Canada*, and a `case` edge from *Canada* to *in*. The one common special case I've seen is possessives, which are now marked with `nmod:poss` and have an associated `case` edge to the "*'s*" token (e.g., *Canada 's hokey team*).